# Reviewing Loschmidt’s paradox in the quantum case?

Tags: time, physics

Boltzmann formulated the Stosszahlansatz :

> Stosszahlansatz is the assumption that the velocities of colliding
> particles are uncorrelated, and independent of position. This means
> the probability that a pair of particles with given velocities will
> collide can be calculated by considering each particle separately and
> ignoring any correlation between the probability for finding one
> particle with velocity $v$ and probability for finding another
> velocity $v$ in a small region $\delta r$.

Now, the [problem](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/391382/150174) Boltzmann dealt with when with H-theorem was:

> someone asked Boltzmann why he could assign a sign to his H-theorem,
> i.e., how could he force time to go in one direction? Boltzmann
> apparently quipped a remark along the lines of "Show me an example
> where it does the opposite.

So there is a formulation emergence of the [Stosszahlansatz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_chaos) in quantum mechanics with density matrices. It's known as "quantum BBGKY hierarchy." Now in papers like:

[Time-reversal invariance of quantum kinetic equations II](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/ctpp.201700052): Density operator formalism:  : The Markov limit of the Born approximation leads to the direction of time.

[Quantum theory of irreversibility](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0378437106013744): A density superoperator is a mathematical object that describes the time evolution of the density matrix of a many-body quantum system. The density superoperator is a time-irreversible object, which means that it can only evolve the density matrix from the past to the future. The paper argues that the irreversibility of the density superoperator is due to the interactions between the particles in the system.

What is the philosophers verdict of these kind of emergent behaviours from interactions to solve Loschmidt’s paradox? A paper which reviews Loschmidt’s paradox in the quantum case would be nice.

Comment: Physics thread about Loschmitt's paradox (mystery) - https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/19970/does-the-scientific-community-consider-the-loschmidt-paradox-resolved-if-so-wha Phonons are the physics model for heat dissipation in solids - https://www.britannica.com/science/phonon. On the macro level heat dissipation via electrical loss or resistive force is associated with a transfer of energy into microscopic phonon vibrations. This does not explain why phonon vibrations do not reverse allowing the macro and micro system and its surroundings to spontaneously reverse to initial state.